# not getting all the properties from Inherited object during REST POST call

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I am facing some issue with REST POST call. I am consuming JSON object. 
Lets suppose I have 2 classes below

```
Class Parent extends Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Key
    protected String Market;
    @Key
    protected String Symbol;
}

Class Child extends Parent
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4252878751127065794L;
    private Double  strikePrice;
    private String  optionType;
}

@POST
@Path("/addProduct")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addProduct(Child child) {
   --somecode--     
}
```

Now I am passing JSON through Postman with all the properties which include all the properties from Parent class also. But when I am debugging this child object it is not giving parent properties. Do I need to use GSON or any other lib for this ?

```
JSON
{
    "Market": "BSE",
    "Symbol": "Infosys",
    "strikePrice": 100,
    "optionType": "Put"
}
```

I can see only strikePrice and optionType with data.

Comment: if we can't see what JSON data you're sending, how are we expected to know whether it will be de-serialised correctly into your class structure, or not?

Comment: I have added JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution. We need to add MessageBodyReader for Custom Response.
I dont know the best practice but it will work without issue.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers;

import common.SerializeUtil;

@Provider
public class CustomMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<Child> {

    @Context
    private Providers providers;

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Parent.class.isAssignableFrom(type); 
    }

    @Override
    public Child readFrom(Class<Child> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String entity = toString(entityStream);
        Child child = SerializeUtil.fromString(entity, Child.class);
        return child;
    }

    public static String toString(InputStream inputStream) {
        return new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8")
                .useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }

}
```

You also need to register this to your service config like below

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.register(CustomMessageBodyReader.class);
```

Please feel free to provide best solution.